# changing separator in a subgroup between markers and splitting in perl 5

Tags: regex, perl

I am reading input lines like this from a file:

```
ewd1    n   river2  n   ne  o   u
    n   <ewd8   ewd9    ewd2>   se
    n   ewd9    s
    n   ewd2    sw
```

I want to split these line by line into an array for processing, but want the items between < and > to be seen as a single entity in one array element without the angle brackets, ideally with the whitespace separators changed to colons. So something like this when called into the array split:

```
@mydata=split(/\s+/,'   n   ewd8:ewd9:ewd2  se');
```

so that

```
@mydata =(' ','n','ewd8:ewd9:ewd2','se');
```

split works fine with the rest of the lines like:

```
    ewd1    n   river2  n   ne  o   u
```

but can't fathom how to do the separator replacement and grouping for the more multi 3rd argument line. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is a more complete example input data lines:

```
ewd1    serpent 0   n   ne  o   u   w   nw  swamp
    bats    0   n   ne  o   u   w   nw  swamp
    undead  0   n   ne  o   u   w   nw  swamp
    n   river2  n   ne  o   u
    1002    e   d
    n   <ewd8   ewd9    ewd2>   se
    n   ewd9    s
    n   ewd2    sw
    n   rough   w   nw  swamp
ewd2    serpent 0   w   nw  n   swamp
    bats    0   w   nw  n   swamp
    undead  0   w   nw  n   swamp
    n   rough   w   nw  n   swamp
    n   <ewd1   ewd9    ewd10>  ne  o
    n   ewd9    e
    n   ewd10   se
    n   ewd4    s
    n   ewd3    sw
```

The fields will be stored in a structured hash table in perl.

Comment: Can you show the expected output please ?

Comment: Match with `/(<[^>]*>|\S+)\s+(<[^>]*>|\S+)\s+(<[^>]*>|\S+)/g`

Comment: Is "n" always the first value? Do you actually need to find that part in your string? Are the items in the 2nd row always "ewd#"? Do you need the contents of the last row? Is the second row the only one that potentially contains multiple items in brackets?

Comment: The lines have different numbers of elements so I don't see how the space (`\s+`) works as a separator -- unless the order doesn't matter?  But then how do you get that first element which is a space? (Is this by any chance tab separated?)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew make that an answer?  but I think you need a special case for the first field which looks to be allowed to be empty

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/81cKk2/3

Answer (score 0):

If you always have three fields per line, you may use

```
/(<[^>]*>|\S+)\s+(<[^>]*>|\S+)\s+(<[^>]*>|\S+)/g
```

Or, in case you have a multiline text and the first field is optional, and if there are any leading/trailing whitespaces:

```
/^\h*(?:(<[^>]*>|\S+)\h+)?(<[^>]*>|\S+)\h+(<[^>]*>|\S+)\h*$/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/81cKk2/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string / line
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `(?:(<[^>]*>|\S+)\h+)?` - an optional sequence (Group 1) of `<`, 0+ chars other than `>`, `>` or 1+ non-whitespace chars followed with 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(<[^>]*>|\S+)` - Group 2: `<`, 0+ chars other than `>`, `>`  or 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(<[^>]*>|\S+)` - Group 3: `<`, 0+ chars other than `>`, `>`  or 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\h*`  - 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string / line

Comment: Thanks for this, in the end I went for a coded solution rather than just a regex as it all got a bit complicated because of variable numbers of separate elements and that the content of each line can differ from line to line.

Comment: @quentinnuk BTW, I see you updated the question. Looks like you want the first non-whitespace chunk, the last one and all in between, right? Try `/^\h*(<[^>]*>|\S+)\h+(.*?)\h+(<[^>]*>|\S+)\h*$/gm`. Check [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/81cKk2/3).

Comment: not quite. I want everything separated by white space as separate fields with whitespace, unless it is in angle brackets, in which case I want the stuff between the angle brackets in a single field with the whitespace in that field changed to (say) ":", so that I can use split on the whole line with a whitespace separator and get the angle bracket stuff as a single element.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did this programatically.

First I chunked the multi element field which could be between angle or square brackets:

```
if ($line =~ /(.+)(<|\[)(.+)(>|\])(.*)\s+/) { # joins multi destination elements together in one field
my $destination=join('|',split(/\s+/,$3));
$line=$1 . "\t" . $destination . "\t" . $5;
}
```

then I processed the $line as a set of individual fields with variable elements.

```
my @args=split(/\s+/,$line);
```